# Detect if a device is being held or is on a table

Tags: android, android-sensors

Which sensors should I use in order to detect if the device is in the user's hand or it is on a table? Any tutorials will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Accelerometer sensor.
Web is full of tutorial and code examples:

[android-sdk-accelerometer-example-tutorial](http://webhole.net/2011/08/20/android-sdk-accelerometer-example-tutorial/)

[github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/38-Sensors](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/38-Sensors)

[AndroidSensor/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html)

[an-android-accelerometer-example](http://xiangchen.wordpress.com/2011/12/17/an-android-accelerometer-example/)

[Orientation sensor](http://android-er.blogspot.it/2010/08/detect-rotation-around-x-y-z-axis-using.html)

and [here](http://www.truststc.org/education/reu/10/Papers/DasGreenPerezMurphy_Paper.pdf) ther's a good white paper on detecting user activities.

Comment: I tried with a sample app and it works in normal use cases. But if I pick up the phone really carefully maintaining its relative position the x,y,z values don't change which is normal. In such case I suppose the only other feedback you can get is the hand pressure applied to a device?

Comment: yes, since all 3 axys can't detect movement, you can use PRESSURE sensore to detect elevation movement.